# issue with slicing 3d array in all 3 dimensions

Tags: python, 3d, slice

I have an issue with slicing of 3d numpy array. 
I have a 3d data array (`zcdata`) for depth of corner points of a physical grid system with the size twice the size of actual grid due to repeat of all corners (adjacent grids share corner points but it is repeated in data set). Assuming the grid has `Nx,Ny,Nz` cells in X,Y, and Z direction; my corner data has a size of `2*Nx, 2*Ny, 2*Nz`

This data is read from a huge ASCII file as a long 1D array and then reshaped into proper 3d format with following code. In my case `Nx, Ny, Nz = (229, 233, 45)` and thus the dimension of zcdata (the corner data array) dimension of `(458 * 466 * 90)` which is a bit large.

```
zcdata is a (2*Nx * 2*Ny * 2*Nz) long array loaded from ASCII file as input:

zcorn_data = zcdata.reshape([2*Nz,2*Ny,2*Nx]).transpose([2,1,0])
```

I am interested in extracting just the unique corner points which is every other index in each direction plus last one corners (so for N cells we need N+1 corner to be defined: simple math: 3 Cells & 4 Corners Example o--o--o--o)
The proper index slice in X,Y,Z is given below:

```
ii = np.append(range(0,2*Nx,2),-1)
jj = np.append(range(0,2*Ny,2),-1)
kk = np.append(range(0,2*Nz,2),-1)
```

Now, try to slice the 3D redundant corner data all at once (with following code line):

```
zcorn_data_1N = zcorn_data[ii,jj,kk]
```

Fails with following error message:

---

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\ISI\Projects\09 Adco-Bab\5 Codes Cleaned\10 SRM Tools-Eclipse.py", line 755, in Read_Grid_CornPts
>
> zcorn_data_1N = zcorn_data[np.append(range(0,2*Nx,2),-1),
>   np.append(range(0,2*Ny,2),-1),np.append(range(0,2*Nz,2),-1)]
>
> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
> ```

---

while the following one-by-one slicing works perfectly:

```
zcorn_data_1N = zcorn_data[:,:,kk]
zcorn_data_1N = zcorn_data_1N[:,jj,:]
zcorn_data_1N = zcorn_data_1N[ii,:,:]
```

I was wondering if I am missing any point here !

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing arrays need to either be the same shape or [broadcastable](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#arrays-broadcasting-broadcastable) into the same shape. Thus, you should resize them (promote their dimensionality) such that their non-singleton dimension is not shared, and they will be broadcastable.

```
ii = np.append(range(0,2*Nx,2),-1)
jj = np.append(range(0,2*Ny,2),-1)
kk = np.append(range(0,2*Nz,2),-1)

ii.resize((Nx+1,1,1))
jj.resize((1,Ny1,1))
kk.resize((1,1,Nz+1))

zcorn_data_1N = zcorn_data[ii,jj,kk]
```